# How to get the list of digits in the scale representing the BigDecimal

Tags: java

I have 3 BigDecimal  objects 9.1, 9.12, 9.123 and I am looking to get the number of digits in the scale which would be 1, 2 and 3 for the above decimals. How do I get this?

Should I get the scale and then do String.length or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("1.2");
bd.scale();//this will return 1

BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("1.23");
bd.scale();//this will return 2

BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("1.234");
bd.scale();//this will return 3
```

**See Also**

- [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#scale())

Answer (score 1):

you can also find it with this way

```
    public static int scale(BigDecimal bd){
           int length = bd.toString().length();
           int longValueLength = Long.toString(bd.longValue()).length();
           int scale =  length - longValueLength - 1;
           return scale;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

           BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal("9.123");
           BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal("9.12233");

           System.out.println(scale(bd1)); // 3
           System.out.println(scale(bd2)); // 5
     }
```

Comment: don;t you like my answer :) ?

Comment: @org.life.java your answer is absolutely correct and much more better than mine. I just want to show something different